# C# / Razor - Access localized string resources from a RazorEngine template

Tags: c#, .net, razor, internationalization, razorengine

I'm building dynamic HTML emails by using RazorEngine to populate a CSHTML template. I need to send emails in multiple languages, and I'd like to use localized string resources within my template to switch languages, like so:

```
@Resources.EmailTemplate.OrderNumberLabel
```

How can I specify the culture used by RazorEngine? It always appears to use the default culture when pulling in strings. I've tried setting the thread culture before parsing with no luck:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);
```

*Note:* I've seen other implementations that have used a different CSHTML file for each language, but I'd like to keep the localized content and the markup separated.

Comment: Have you tried setting `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` instead of, or in addition to, `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: In addition to what @Mark said, can you also check your resx files properties, and if it's not already like this "Build Action: Embedded Resource; Copy to Output Directory: Do Not Copy" can you change it accordingly and try again.

Comment: *headdesk* @Mark, you're the winner - if you write up an answer I'll approve it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` property instead of, or in addition to, the `CurrentCulture` property.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at The localized templates service here 
http://netmvc.blogspot.ca/2012/04/localizable-text-template-engine-using.html